# Subtitles suddenly appearing in videos

Tags: video-conversion

I have been converting files in order to reduce size, and I notice some of the converted videos now have subtitles where there were none before.  I am using the Leawo converter, and the subtitle setting is disabled.  There is no SRT file or anything of the sort.
What's causing this?
Thanks

Comment: Some files (containers) like MKV and others have one or more sibtitles tracks inside. Your software is probably picking up those. It looks crappy/scammy and without much room for settings - it doesn't even mention subtitles in the tech specs...